# htaccess rewrite, in an array?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Say I have the following pages:

```
http://www.site.com/folder/page.php?id=89
http://www.site.com/folder/page.php?id=85
http://www.site.com/folder/page.php?id=camel+hump
http://www.site.com/folder/page.php?id=76
http://www.site.com/folder/page.php?id=71
http://www.site.com/folder/page.php?id=frog
http://www.site.com/folder/page.php?id=62
http://www.site.com/folder/page.php?id=59
```

and I want to direct the following:

89, 79, 44, camel+hump to the following page:

```
http://www.site.com/folder/page/$1
```

EG:

```
http://www.site.com/folder/camel-hump (Notice the + replaced with a -)
```

and everything else to the following page:

```
http://www.site.com/folder/overview
```

How would I do this?

Basically, I have around 200 pages that need redirecting, and they all have the same URL apart from the get parameter, some of them need redirecting to a `/folder/get-parameter` page and the rest need redirecting to a `/folder/overview` page.

I also need + signs to be replaced with - signs, so for example `camel+hump` becomes `camel-hump`

How can I do this with a rewrite rule? Something like:

```
if match (89|79|44|camel+hump|frog) go to /folder/$1 (but replace + with -)
```

everything else, go to `/folder/overview`

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
# Filter out the query string values for id that you want to rewrite
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(89|79|44|camel\+hump|frog)
RewriteRule ^folder/page.php$ /folder/page/%1?  [L]

# get rid of the +
RewriteRule ^folder/page/(.+)\+(.+)$ /folder/page/$1-$2 [L]
```

Comment: For some reason + aren't being replaced with - signs, any idea?

Comment: Those rules work precisely as advertised when I put them in my .htaccess file. It looks like you've changed them to fit your setup in your other question.