# replace character in rewrite rule

Tags: mod-rewrite

Here are my current rules:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^to=(one|seventeen|thirty\+four)
RewriteRule ^/folder/page.php$ http://www.site.com/folder/category/%1?  [L]
RewriteRule ^folder/category/(.+)\+(.+)$ http://www.site.com/folder/category/$1-$2 [L]
```

The first rule works fine, it redirects perfectly if the word is in the query string, but I can't get thirty+four to become thirty-four when redirected.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, `RewriteRule ^/folder/page.php$` will never match anything. The URI's get the prefix (the leading slash) removed if the rules are in an .htaccess file instead of server config.

Secondly, since you've included `http://www.site.com/` in your targets, that means the browser will get redirected instead of internally rewritten. You need to remove `http://www.site.com/` from your first rule so that the second one can be applied.

Comment: Where did our so wisely named `user1088771` talked about `.htaccess` file? I mean... maybe it should be better to say "will never match anything **if in an `.htaccess` file**.

Comment: But I understand that giving just "clues" to people and not doing their full job is clever than what I do ;)

Comment: I can't catch you up with your reputation, you're too good for me. Please do more "bounty" =)

Comment: I assumed it was in an htaccess file because it was tagged, also related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8529848/htaccess-rewrite-in-an-array

Comment: This isn't in a htaccess file, its in a vhost file.

Comment: If that's the case, you need to add a **/** in front of the `folder/category/(.+)\+(.+)$` expression and remove the .htaccess tag from your question. But the second note still applies.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what should work:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^to=(one|seventeen|thirty\+four)
RewriteRule ^folder/page.php$ folder/category/%1  [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^folder/category/(.+)\+(.+)$ folder/category/$1-$2 [NC,QSA,L]
```

### And now three hints:

### 1)

Please make sure you've read **everything** here before asking:

- Here's the wiki of [serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/questions/214512/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-mod-rewrite-rules-but-were-afraid-to-as)
- The [howto's htaccess official guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html)
- The [official mod_rewrite guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

### 2)

Please try to use the `RewriteLog` directive: it helps you to track down problems:

```
# Trace:
# (!) file gets big quickly, remove in prod environments:
RewriteLog "/web/logs/mywebsite.rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 9
RewriteEngine On
```

### 3)

My favorite tool to check for regexp:

http://www.quanetic.com/Regex (don't forget to choose ereg(POSIX) instead of preg(PCRE)!)

You use this tool when you want to check the URL and see if they're valid or not.

Comment: This doesn't work either, it redirects to: folder/category/thirty+four?to=thirty+four